# Can I have/use Cursor.Postion in float? OR smooth cursor movement?

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using Cursor.Position property to manipulate the position of the cursor in my program.
It uses the integer datatype and the movement of the cursor is not smooth; it seems jerky...

Is there a way to use single or floating datatypes?

My sole purpose is to have smooth cursor movement in real time, that is, no simlulations...

Comment: The cursor position is in pixel offset... what would 1.5 pixels of offset even be?

Comment: If you move the mouse by hand, does this movement ok?

Comment: My money is on the OP using DoEvents().

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no simulations"? To me, "non-simulated cursor movement" means that the physical input device (the mouse, for example) has to cause the movement, but I'm assuming you're *not* asking how to move the mouse on my desk.

Answer (score 2):

The jerkiness is not a result of it being an `int`, as the cursor *can* only be at a particular pixel location on the screen; having floating-point precision would be wasted, since the cursor can't be in between pixels.

The jerkiness is likely coming from whatever timing mechanism you're using to perform the movement. Can you share that code with us?